# jqueryのラジオボタンで任意のオプションチェックしたいです。

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="hoge" class="hoge-select" >
    <option selected="selected" value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
    <option value="4">text4</option>
    <option value="5">text5</option>
</select>
```

jqueryのラジオボタンで任意のオプションチェックしたいです。
例えばvalue="2"にチェックしたい場合はどのように書けばいいですか？

Comment: セレクトボックでした。すみません。

Comment: 質問の下にある[edit]リンクからタイトルや本文は編集できるので、書き間違いや補足があればそちらをお使いください。また質問が解決したときはお礼コメントもいいですが、回答左のチェックマークをクリックすることで「この回答で質問が解決した」という目印になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLの `selected` 属性をちゃんと付け外ししたい場合は `attr()` `removeAttr()` を使わないといけませんが、通常は `prop()` か `val()` を使えばいいかと。

- `<option>` の `selected` プロパティを true にする

  ```
  // 択一のselectやradioでは、どれかtrueにした時点で他はfalseになるので↓は不要
  // $("#hoge option:selected").prop("selected", false);
  $("#hoge option[value=2]").prop("selected", true);
  ```

  用途：value以外の方法で要素を指定したい時（n番目とか既存のjQueryオブジェクトとか）。複数選択可能な場合は個別に切り替えたい時に使います。
- `<select>` の `value` プロパティを変更する

  ```
  // .prop() でもいいが、専用の .val() が使える
  // ここで指定する値は `<option>` の `value` 属性に指定した文字列
  $("#hoge").val("3");
  ```

  用途：選択したい要素のvalueを知っている時。`$("option[value=" + val + "]")` なんて文字列操作をせずに済みます。また複数選択可能な場合は、値を配列で渡すことで一括選択に使います。

なお `<input type="radio">` は `<select>` のようにまとめる要素がないので、前者は同じように動作しますが後者は少し変わってきます。この手の要素の選択値の取得・設定については次のページなどがよくまとまっているかと思います。参考までに。

[jQueryにおけるフォーム値の取得と設定 : JavaScript好き](http://jszuki.doorblog.jp/archives/31702159.html)

Comment: 丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。解決できました。

Answer (score 1):

`$("#hoge option:selected").removeAttr("selected");`
`$("#hoge option[value=2]").attr("selected", "selected");`

でいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！！！